# multiprocessing.Process doesn't terminate after putting requests response.content to queue

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to run multiple API requests in parallel with multiprocessing.Process and requests. I put urls to parse into JoinableQueue instance and put back the content to the Queue instance. I've noticed that putting response.content into the Queue somehow prevents the process from terminating.

Here's simplified example with just 1 process (Python 3.5):

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import queue
import requests
import time


class ChildProcess(mp.Process):
    def __init__(self, q, qout):
        super().__init__()
        self.qin = qin
        self.qout = qout
        self.daemon = True

    def run(self):
        while True:
            try:
                url = self.qin.get(block=False)
                r = requests.get(url, verify=False)
                self.qout.put(r.content)
                self.qin.task_done()
            except queue.Empty:
                break
            except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
                print(self.name, e)
                self.qin.task_done()
        print("Infinite loop terminates")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    qin = mp.JoinableQueue()
    qout = mp.Queue()
    for _ in range(5):
        qin.put('http://en.wikipedia.org')
    w = ChildProcess(qin, qout)
    w.start()
    qin.join()
    time.sleep(1)
    print(w.name, w.is_alive())
```

After running the code I get:

> Infinite loop terminates
>
> ChildProcess-1 True

Please help to understand why the process doesn't terminate after run function exits.

Update: added print statement to show the loop terminates

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. The last line of the "run" function of my Process-inheriting object executes, but the process doesn't die. Still haven't found the answer (my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57780333/my-process-finishes-its-run-function-but-it-doesnt-die)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a call to [w.terminate()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.terminate) above the print message.

---

Regarding why the process doesn't terminate itself; your function code is an infinite loop, so it doesn't ever return. Calling terminate signals the process to kill itself.

Comment: Thanks, it works. But what's the actual reason why the process doesn't terminate by itself?

Comment: This is not the correct reason for why the process doesn't terminate - the code outputs "Infinite loop terminates", indicating it has exited the loop (because of the `break` statement).

Answer (score 6):

As noted in the [Pipes and Queues documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html#pipes-and-queues)

> if a child process has put items on a queue (and it has not used
>   JoinableQueue.cancel_join_thread), then that process will not
>   terminate until all buffered items have been flushed to the pipe.
>
> This means that if you try joining that process you may get a deadlock
>   unless you are sure that all items which have been put on the queue
>   have been consumed.
>
> ...
>
> **Note that a queue created using a manager does not have this issue.**

If you switch over to a manager queue, then the process terminates successfully:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import queue
import requests
import time


class ChildProcess(mp.Process):
    def __init__(self, q, qout):
        super().__init__()
        self.qin = qin
        self.qout = qout
        self.daemon = True

    def run(self):
        while True:
            try:
                url = self.qin.get(block=False)
                r = requests.get(url, verify=False)
                self.qout.put(r.content)
                self.qin.task_done()
            except queue.Empty:
                break
            except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
                print(self.name, e)
                self.qin.task_done()
        print("Infinite loop terminates")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = mp.Manager()
    qin = mp.JoinableQueue()
    qout = manager.Queue()
    for _ in range(5):
        qin.put('http://en.wikipedia.org')
    w = ChildProcess(qin, qout)
    w.start()
    qin.join()
    time.sleep(1)
    print(w.name, w.is_alive())
```

Comment: The process terminates successfully, but you're running the risk of losing data in the queue. If you're fine with that, then this approach works fine.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit hard to figure this out based on the `Queue` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/queue.html#queue.Queue) - I struggled with the same problem.

The key concept here is that before a producer thread terminates, it joins any queues that it has `put` data into; that join then blocks until the queue's background thread terminates, **which only happens when the queue is empty**. So basically, before your `ChildProcess` can exit, someone has to consume all the stuff it `put` into the queue!

There is some documentation of the `Queue.cancel_join_thread` function, which is supposed to circumvent this problem, but I couldn't get it to have any effect - maybe I'm not using it correctly.

Here's an example modification you can make that should fix the issue:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    qin = mp.JoinableQueue()
    qout = mp.Queue()
    for _ in range(5):
        qin.put('http://en.wikipedia.org')
    w = ChildProcess(qin, qout)
    w.start()
    qin.join()
    while True:
        try:
            qout.get(True, 0.1)     # Throw away remaining stuff in qout (or process it or whatever,
                                    # just get it out of the queue so the queue background process
                                    # can terminate, so your ChildProcess can terminate.
        except queue.Empty:
            break
    w.join()                # Wait for your ChildProcess to finish up.
    # time.sleep(1)         # Not necessary since we've joined the ChildProcess
    print(w.name, w.is_alive())
```