# Terminate two processes that have a pipe connection - Multiprocessing Python

Tags: python, process, multiprocessing, pipe

I've made two processes and each process has one end of the pipe. When I terminate my process, I get a "BrokenPipeError". How do I correctly kill the processes. I'm using Process, not subprocess! `import multiprocessing` I'm suspecting it's because Process1's pipe is still trying to send information. How do I end the processes without having this error?

I also have a GUI that send the kill command to my processes when it closes.

I've tried:

`process.terminate()` and `process.join()`
But I still get the broken pipe error.

```
import multiprocessing as mp


...#other code

my_pipe = mp.Pipe()
other_pipe1 = mp.Pipe()
other_pipe2 = mp.Pipe()

process1 = mp.Process(my_pipe[0], other_pipe1[0])
process2 = mp.Process(my_pipe[1], other_pipe2[0])


..... #doing things in my processes. Sending data from process1 to process2


#When I close my GUI
other_pipe1[1].send("kill")  #Process1 closes some files
**while(1):**
   if(other_pipe1[1].poll()):
      if(other_pipe1[1].recv() == "done"):   #Process1 send a message back once files closed
         process1.join()
         process2.join()
         **break**
```

Comment: Use [multiprocessing.Event](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Event) to terminate your processes gracefully. Don't use [`mp.terminate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.terminate) read the warning.

Comment: Thanks for that. However, I tried mp.join() but that didn't terminate the process. How would I use multiprocessing.Event to terminate the process? The Event class only sets flags but doesn't actually terminate anything.
[link]https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Event

Comment: ***"Event class only sets flags"***: Yes, a `process` runs usually in a `while True:` loop. Do `while not <myevent>.is_set():`. Otherwise i missunderstood your intention?

Comment: I included the while loop along with the break statement. ^^Look at the edits I made in the code.
My processes have their own run() with while loops that are supposed to terminate when they receive a "kill" message. However, my ```other_pipe1[0].poll()``` in process1 doesn't seem to be working if I send over a lot of information through the pipe that connects Process1 and Process2. If I send less info between the processes, then ```other_pipe1[0].poll()``` become ```True``` otherwise it's ```False``` which is very strange.

Comment: you have to ignore  SIGPIPE signal

Comment: @John: See [my-process-finishes-its-run-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57780333/my-process-finishes-its-run-function-but-it-doesnt-die) for a typical `Event` use case.

Comment: @bigdataolddriver What do you mean by ignore SIGPIPE signal? And how would I do so?

Comment: @stovfl I've tried implementing that use of Event but I still have the same problem. Process1 sends CAN data to Process2 via a pipe. I also send data from Process2 to main. When I close my GUI, I send a kill message to Process1 and Process2 which should stop their run() loops. However, Only Process1 stops. Process2 hangs even though I force its while loop (in its run() ) condition to be false.

Comment: @John: ***"Process2 hangs"***: Is any of the function which `process2` uses `blocking`? Therfore the `process` can not terminate gracefully. Rethink about your question: Did you asking for **A** but want a answer for **B**?